# Error on the result vector

Tags: c++, cuda

My problem is that when I make the multiplication it only multiplies the the first row of the matrix with the first element of the vector and the next elements makes them zero so the result vector gives a wrong result.

```
using namespace std;
#define N 100
#define F 3
#define X 7
__global__ void matvec(int *MAT, int *VEC, int *SOL) {
  int bx = blockIdx.x;
  int tx = threadIdx.x;
  int i = 32*bx+tx;
  for (int j = 0; j < X; j++) {
    SOL[i] = ((MAT[i * X + j] * VEC[j]) +SOL[i]) % 2;
  }
}
int main () {
int i, j;
int MAT[N][N], VEC[N], SOL[N];
int *MAT_dev, *VEC_dev, *SOL_dev;
size_t nBytes = X * X * sizeof(int);

cout << "\t- - - - - MATRIX - - - - -\n\n";
for (i = 0; i < X; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < X; j++) {
      cout << "Element [" << i << "][" << j << "]: ";
      cin >> MAT[i][j];
  }
 }
cout << endl << endl;
for (i = 0; i < X; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < X; j++) {
    cout << MAT[i][j] << " ";
    if (j == (X - 1))
        cout << endl;
  }
 }
cout << endl << endl;
cout << "\t- - - - - VECTOR - - - - -\n\n";
for (i = 0; i < X; i++) {
  cout << "Element [" << i << "]: ";
  cin >> VEC[i];
}
cout << endl << endl;
for (i = 0; i < X; i++) {
  cout << VEC[i] << " ";
}
cout << endl << endl;

cudaMalloc((void**)&MAT_dev, nBytes);
cudaMalloc((void**)&VEC_dev, nBytes);
cudaMalloc((void**)&SOL_dev, nBytes);

cudaMemcpy(MAT_dev, MAT, nBytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(VEC_dev, VEC, nBytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

dim3 dimBlock(X,X);
dim3 dimGrid(1,1);

matvec<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(MAT_dev, VEC_dev, SOL_dev);

cudaMemcpy(SOL, SOL_dev, nBytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

cout << "\t- - - - - RESULT - - - - -\n\n";
for (i = 0; i < X; i++)
{
  cout << SOL[i] << " ";
}
cout << endl << endl;

cudaFree(MAT_dev);
cudaFree(VEC_dev);
cudaFree(SOL_dev);

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: What is your question?  You've only explained that you've written code and you don't like what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the size of `MAT` is much larger than it should be.  Basically you need `N == X`, which shouldn't be a problem because both are known at compile time.  Memory for a 2D array is laid out in a single contiguous block, row major for C--so in your case the first row corresponds to the first 400 (`sizeof(int)*N`) bytes, the second row to the second 400, etc.  The length of the row is called the 'stride'  However, `cudaMemcpy` has no idea what the stride is or which elements of `MAT` have been filled in, it just copies the first `nBytes` bytes from `MAT` into `MAT_DEV`.  Since `nBytes` is `sizeof(int)*X*X` and `X` == 7 << `N` the second and subsequent rows of your matrix never get copied.  Only the first 196 bytes from the `MAT` get copied, explaining why your second row is all zeros.

Comment: Thanks Matt Phillips it really helped. I only change my N number to the same number of X and worked. Explaining about the second row, maybe got confused a little, what i meant was, the first value of the result vector was ok the rest of the values (the next 6 values) were the ones that return them zeros. Buy with your answer it did copied the rest of the rows and made the multiplication.

Comment: @Scabro93 Glad it worked out.  But the zeros in your output vector make perfect sense--the matrix, as imported into CUDA, was all zeros starting with the second row for the reasons I went into.  So multiplying by a vector results in a non-zero first element with the rest zeros.